# C# casting child class to parent interface with type parameters fails

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, casting

Having defined the following:

```
public interface IFoo { }
public interface IBar<IFoo> { }

public class Foo : IFoo { }
public class Bar : IBar<Foo> { }
```

This line throws error:

```
IBar<IFoo> test = (IBar<IFoo>) new Bar();

"Unable to cast object of type 'Bar' to type 'IBar'1[IFoo]'
```

Why is that? How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: If you define the second interface as `public interface IBar<out IFoo>` you can cast it. Google 'covariance'.

Comment: Also, the question set up as the answer is a different case. That one doesn't have interfaces like this one does.